# Django cannot assign, "Rating.exercise" must be a "Exercise" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

[Localhost Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyY3I.png)
I have following requirement:

- There are exercises and there are ratings
- An exercise can have multiple ratings

My goal is to add ratings to the exercises dynamically i.e. I have created all the exercises before hand and rating to a particular exercise I should be able add afterwards calling some function. When I hit '**save_rating**' view I get the error "*Cannot assign "[]": "Rating.exercise" must be a "Exercise" instance.*"

What am I doing wrong?

My models.py looks like following

```
class Exercise(models.Model):

#Field for storing exercise type
EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('BS', 'Best stretch'),
    ('BR', 'Butterfly reverse'),
    ('SR', 'Squat row'),
    ('PL', 'Plank'),
    ('PU', 'Push up'),
    ('SP', 'Side plank'),
    ('SQ', 'Squat'),
)
exercise_type = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES)
#Field for storing intensity level
INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Really simple'),
    (2, 'Rather Simple'),
    (3, 'Simple'),
    (4, 'Okay'),
    (5, 'Difficult'),
    (6, 'Rather Difficult'),
    (7, 'Really Difficult'),
)

intensity_level = models.IntegerField(choices=INTENSITY_LEVEL_CHOICES)
#Field for storing video url for a particular exercise
video_url = models.URLField()
#Field for storing description of the exercise
description = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Rating(models.Model):

#Field for storing exercise type
exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, related_name='ratings', blank=True, null=True)
#Field for storing rating
RATING_CHOICES = (
    ('H', 'Happy'),
    ('N', 'Neutral'),
    ('S', 'Sad'),
)
value = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

I have defined my serializer like following:

```
class RatingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
class Meta:
    model = Rating
    fields = ('value')

class ExerciseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
  exercise_type = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
  intensity_level = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
  video_url = serializers.URLField(required=True)
  description = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
  ratings = RatingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

My views:

```
def exercise_list(request):
 """
 List all exercises.
 """
 if request.method == 'GET':
    exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(exercise_type='BS', intensity_level=1)
    serializer = ExerciseSerializer(exercises, many=True)
    return JSONResponse(serializer.data)


def save_rating(request):
 """
 Save a rating for a specific exercise.
 """
 #Get a specific exercise for which you want to save the rating
  specificExercise = Exercise.objects.filter(exercise_type='BS' , intensity_level=1)

 #Create a rating and pass the specific exercise reference to it
  Rating.objects.create(exercise = specificExercise, value='H')
  #serializer = ExerciseSerializer(rating, many=True)
  serializer = ExerciseSerializer(instance=specificExercise)
  return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `save_rating`, you are having `specificExercise` as a queryset not one `Exercise` instance, so when you do:

```
Rating.objects.create(exercise=specificExercise, value='H')
```

You try to assign a queryset to your `exercise` field, which of course doesn't work.

Simple fix would be using `get` instead of `filter` so you got one instance. But you also have to make sure the `get` query doesn't throw `DoesNotExist` exception, so a simple `try except` would do.

**Edit:**

```
def save_rating(request):
    """
     Save a rating for a specific exercise.
     """
     # Get a specific exercise for which you want to save the rating
     try:
         specificExercise = Exercise.objects.get(exercise_type='BS',
                                                 intensity_level=1)
         # Create a rating and pass the specific exercise reference to it
         Rating.objects.create(exercise = specificExercise, value='H')
         # serializer = ExerciseSerializer(rating, many=True)
         serializer = ExerciseSerializer(instance=specificExercise)
         return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
     except Exercise.DoesNotExist:
         # TODO: you need to return some error indication that there's no such exercise
         return None
```

Please read django doc about [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

Comment: Can you please also tell me how it can fixed? I am relatively new to Django.
When I modify my line to 
exercises = Exercise.objects.get(exercise_type='BS', intensity_level=1) it create two blank ratings in the exercise but value of the rating i.e. 'H' is not inserted.

Comment: I edited my answer. But I do want you to understand why your code doesn't work. Please read more django doc to get familiar with it and see if it makes sense:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Comment: Sure! Your answer did work, it's just that ratings saved are blank. 
Rating.objects.create(exercise = specificExercise, value='H'), value 'H' is however not inserted.

Comment: How did you verify that value is empty? Can you do a query in django shell?

Comment: My localhost is running and when I hit the url I can see the JSON data for that particular exercise. I have attached a sceenshot to the question as posing that JSON in comment is too messy.

Comment: Maybe the way you compose the JSON data is wrong, can you check directly in the database for `value` field?

Comment: Yes you are correct, the values were stored in the database. However I will need to modify my view to extract the actual value i.e. 'H' of the rating.